# Can a Japanese word combine both on'yomi and kun'yomi characters?

Tags: pronunciation, onyomi

I would like to know whether a Japanese word combining at least two kanji can combine both on'yomi and kun'yomi characters, within the same word.

Comment: Yes... See [湯桶読み](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B9%AF%E6%A1%B6%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF) and [重箱読み](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%87%8D%E7%AE%B1%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF)

Answer (score 14):

The answer is yes. There are "重箱読み (ju-bako-yomi)" and "湯桶読み (yu-tou-yomi)" in Japanese vocabulary (in 2 kanji words only).

重箱 is read as Ju-bako. "Ju" is on'yomi and "bako" is kun'yomi. Like this, it is called 重箱読み when 1st kanji is on'yomi and 2nd kanji is kun'yomi.

湯桶 is read as Yu-tou. "Yu" is kun'yomi and "tou" is on'yomi. Like this, it is called 湯桶読み when 1st kanji is kun'yomi and 2nd kanji is on'yomi.

Other examples:

> 王様(ou-sama) : on + kun --> 重箱読み
> 味方(mi-kata) : on + kun --> 重箱読み
> 丸太(maru-ta) : kun + on --> 湯桶読み
> 見本(mi-hon ) : kun + on --> 湯桶読み

Answer (score 5):

Sii's answer is a good one.

To add a clarification, you asked:

> Can a Japanese word combine both on'yomi and kun'yomi characters?

Japanese **characters** are neither *on'yomi* or *kun'yomi*.  The **characters** are just graphical representations.

The words *on'yomi* and *kun'yomi* describe the **readings** for Japanese characters (specifically *kanji*).  That's actually what the *yomi* part means: it literally means "reading".

For kanji, most characters have multiple readings: usually at least one *on'yomi*, and usually at least one *kun'yomi*.

- The word *on'yomi* is spelled 音【おん】読【よ】み, literally meaning 音【おん】 (*on*, "sound") + 読【よ】み (*yomi*, "reading").  The *on'yomi* pronunciation of any kanji usually derives from Middle Chinese, as the Japanese approximation of the **sound** of the Chinese word when it was borrowed from Middle Chinese over 1300 years ago.
- The word *kun'yomi* is spelled 訓【くん】読【よ】み, literally meaning 訓【くん】 (*kun*, "meaning") + 読【よ】み (*yomi*, "reading").  The *kun'yomi* pronunciation of any kanji usually derives from native Japanese vocabulary, as the Japanese approximation of the **meaning** of the Chinese word when it was borrowed from Middle Chinese over 1300 years ago.

1300+ years is a long time, and some things have changed over that period.  Some kanji are even relatively recent inventions, such as 腺【せん】 (*sen*, "gland").  And language is always irregular.  There are consequently exceptions here and there, such as kanji that have only *on'yomi* and no *kun'yomi* (like 腺【せん】), or kanji that have only *kun'yomi* and no *on'yomi* (like 畑【はたけ】 [*hatake*, "dry cultivated field"]).  There have also been sound shifts in both Chinese and Japanese, so the Chinese word 十 is pronounced as *shí* in Mandarin, but as *jū* in Japanese -- these both derive from Middle Chinese pronunciation //d͡ʑiɪp̚// (roughly similar to the pronunciation of the English word *Jeep*).

**To summarize**, remember that Japanese characters **have** *yomi*, but the characters themselves are not *yomi*.

Comment: and how do you pronounce /d͡ʑiɪp̚/ ....? o_d͡ʑ

Comment: @a20, apologies, that's the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) -- the pronunciation is not too far off from the English pronunciation of the word _**Jeep**_.

Comment: thanks! I know that the phonetic alphabet is more exact, but I would think that most people are not very fluent in it, so it is always nice to add an approximate example in e.g. English (d͡ʑ__^)