# is it normal to sometimes read compound kanji with kun reading

Tags: kanji

shouldnt compound kanji be read with on reading i came by the word 子供 but the kanji here are read with their kun readings being こ and ども
thanks for any help

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly normal. I hope it helped ;-)

Comment: You know what, we even have kun+on and on+kun reading compounds! :D https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40437/9831

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it normal to sometimes read compound kanji with kun reading?

Sometimes yes, but as a whole this kind of reading is exceptional. As for the reason, it took me a decent long time to collect these examples.

◎訓読み〔[訓読み＋訓読み](https://ameblo.jp/chibi8taco/entry-11870860564.html)〕：和語

青空（あお＋ぞら）　　裏庭（うら＋にわ）　　薬指（くすり＋ゆび）　　毛玉（け＋だま）

坂道（さか＋みち）　　花園（はな＋ぞの）　　丸太（まる＋た）　　横顔（よこ＋がお）

◎[訓読みだけの](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1010148070)　牧場（まき＋ば）・細道（ほそ＋みち）・夕方（ゆう＋がた）

◎[訓読み＋訓読みの熟語](http://kanjinozatsugaku.blog.jp/archives/8923232.html)　・家路（いえ＋じ）・霜柱（しも＋ばしら）・手紙（て＋がみ）

[◎【訓読みさせる二字熟語】](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11142171781)　海松(うみまつ)、海嘯(うみなり)、垂水(たるみ)、鳴水(なるみ)、弓月(ゆみづき、ゆづき)、観月(みづき)、山肌(やまはだ)、山脈(やまなみ)、山峡(やまかい)、山沢(やまさわ)、沢渡(さわたり、さわわたり)、沢瀉(おもだか)、蒼天(あおぞら)、稲妻(いなづま)、稲光(いなびかり)
「草木」＝「くさき」、「竹林」＝「たけばやし」、「水面」＝「みなも」
滝壺（たきつぼ）、山川（やまかわ）、野原（のはら）、谷底（たにぞこ）

◎　人柄(ひと＋がら)　手数（て＋かず）　昼間（ひる＋ま）　人手（ひと＋で）

Comment: are they like exceptions to the rule that compound kanji are read with onyomi? or can i just read kanjI with either their kun or on

Comment: @Hamzeh: They are exceptions. To tell you the truth,  it took me a decent long time to collect these 訓読み+訓読み compound words because they are exceptions.