# Are groups of kanji classified as on or kun'yomi overall or individually?

Tags: words, kanji, readings

Individual kanji have on and kun readings. Which character in a multiple kanji word determines if the word has an on or kun reading? 月曜日 is a better example, on on kun. Would Nichiyoubi be considered an onyomi or kunyomi word?

Comment: "ni", "hon", "jin" are all on readings. How can it be kun when three on readings are combined?

Comment: I dont know why the question was downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most multi-kanji words have either only on-readings or only kun-readings, but there are exceptions. For example, 時計 is neither purely kun nor purely on. (と is a kun-reading, けい is an on-reading)

Words like 時計 are called **kun-on compounds** or **湯桶読み**. Likewise, words like 毎年 is called **on-kun compounds** or **重箱読み**.

See: [Can a Japanese word combine both on'yomi and kun'yomi characters?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40433/5010)

Comment: 時計ですが、現在の漢字は当て字なので例とするにはあまり適していないと思います… http://gogen-allguide.com/to/tokei.html